# Trim the part of composition in After Effects along with its key frames

Tags: after-effects, workflow

I want to trim a composition b/w the two *Composition marker (1)* and *Composition marker (2)*:

[image: After Effects screenshot]

You see there are many layers with different key frames and I want to trim everything which lies in the selection area. So the rest of the part of the composition (left and right of the two *Composition marker (1)* and *Composition marker (2)*) combines and becomes a complete composition.

Comment: wait, so you want to make everything after 2 a seperate composition, and before 1 also a seperate composition? why don't you just precomp it, drag it to a new composition and trim it, this way you can retain everything in this comp, but edit the length in the comp with the precomp?

Comment: Thanks Alex ! Yeah I can do that. But in that case I need to work on two compositions and things will become messy after that. I was thinking if there is way just to achieve this in this composition itself.

Comment: For a **better workflow**, see this answers: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/how-to-view-my-project-elements-while-working-in-a-composition/

Comment: If you right-click on the work area bar there's something called extract work area and lift(?) work area. They delete everything outside of or inside of the work area, which is kinda what you want to do (you'll have to copy and paste a bit). I don't know if it will simplify your project.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex suggested, *precomping* is the answer to your question. There is no other way to have two separate compositions within one composition. Precomping is a normal part of the After Effects workflow, and is in fact necessary for many effects to work properly with nested elements.

It need not be messy – just organize your project well and label everything clearly. Learning to navigate between your *comps* with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will help you to use this workflow efficiently.

Comment: related: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/15291/6685